# Issue in click function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u55L3skz/1/

This is jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {

        alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );

    });

});
```

Here what is the mistake? I am new to jquery.

When click the link it will shows alert message right?

But it didn't shows.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to include jQuery first.

Comment: jquery not added to the page(look at `Frameworks & Extensions` in the left panel of jsfiddle) - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u55L3skz/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add jQuery to JS fiddle :) Other than that code works, see [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tc329pL4/). However it's safer to use a different DOM ready function (see below) this will avoid conflict with other frameworks you may use.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("a").click(function() {
         alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
    });     
});
```

Comment: Ok, in jsfiddle is easy to add.. then how to write jquery in my editor?

Comment: You should just create a HTML page, then link jquery to it. See this http://pastebin.com/GHDwxUnC for full sample.